# Applying key bindings to state transitions when implementing a state pattern

Tags: java, key-bindings, state-pattern

here's a programming style question about the best strategy to map input keys to actions in a class that implement the state pattern.

I'm dealing with two classes:

The first implements the state pattern, which controls a multi-state physical device:

```
class DeviceController {
    State _a, _b, _current;

    // Actions that may prompt a transition from one state to another
    public void actionA() { ... }
    public void actionB() { ... }
    public void actionC() { ... }

    public State getStateA() { ... }
    public State getStateB() { ... }

    public void setCurrentState() { ... }
};
```

The second is a KeyListener that retrieves all keyboard input and calls the appropriate action from the device controller when a pressed input key matches a (for the time being) hard-coded bindings table:

```
class KeyDemo implements KeyListener {

    DeviceController _controller;
    ...
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        char key = Character.toUpperCase(arg0.getKeyChar());
        switch (key) {
        case 'A':
            _controller.actionA();
            break;
        case 'B' :
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Is there a best-practice coding style to bind the keys to the actions in the controller ? Do I have to go through a switch statement, as in the sample code ? It seems to me that this solution is somewhat dirty code: isn't the state pattern supposed to eliminate unmaintanable if and switch control structures ?

Thank you for your suggenstions.

Answer (score 0):

Using polymorphism you can achive your goal. I've used enum but maybe it would be more appropriated to use interfaces or an abstract class and then implement each of the key processors. What do you think?

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

enum KeyProcessor {
    A {
        void executeAction() {
            _controller.actionA();
        }
    },
    B {
        void executeAction() {
            _controller.actionB();
        }
    };

    private static final DeviceController _controller = new DeviceController();

    void executeAction() {
        System.out.println("no action defined");
    }
}

class DeviceController {
    State _a;
    State _b;
    State _current;

    // Actions that may prompt a transition from one state to another
    public void actionA() {
        System.out.println("action A performed.");

    }

    public void actionB() {
        System.out.println("action B performed.");
    }

    public void actionC() {
    }

    public State getStateA() {
        return null;
    }

    public State getStateB() {
        return null;
    }

    public void setCurrentState() {
    }
} // end class DeviceController

public class KeyDemo implements KeyListener {

    DeviceController _controller;

    // ...
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        keyPressed(Character.toUpperCase(arg0.getKeyChar()));
        // ...
    }

    public void keyPressed(char c) {
        KeyProcessor processor = KeyProcessor.valueOf(c + "");
        if (processor != null) {
        processor.executeAction();
    }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        KeyDemo main = new KeyDemo();
        main.keyPressed('A');
        main.keyPressed('B');
    }
} // end class KeyDemo

class State {
}
```